# Getting the base form of a word using the Java Wordnet Library

Tags: nlp, semantics, wordnet

I'm using the Java WordNet Library (`JWNL`) for my project, and I need to find base form of a word before processing.

For example, the base form of the word "sent" should be "send". Likewise, the base form of the word "dispatched" should be "dispatch". I have read the [JWNL documentation](https://jwordnet.sourceforge.net/handbook.html) but it confuses me. Could someone please provide me a piece of code that finds the base word?

Answer (score 2):

I used JAWS as I found it better then JWNL check this code out to find base for and gloss about it

```
import java.io.*;
import edu.smu.tspell.wordnet.*;

/**
 * Displays word forms and definitions for synsets containing the word form
 * specified on the command line. To use this application, specify the word
 * form that you wish to view synsets for, as in the following example which
 * displays all synsets containing the word form "airplane":
 * <br>
 * java TestJAWS airplane
 */
public class start
{
    /**
     * Main entry point. The command-line arguments are concatenated together
     * (separated by spaces) and used as the word form to look up.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if (args.length == 0)
            {
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String wordForm = null;//"fast";//buffer.toString();
                System.out.print("\n");
                System.out.print("Enter your query: ");
                   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                   try {
                     wordForm = br.readLine();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                     System.out.println("Error!");
                     System.exit(1);
                   }
                   System.out.println("Your looking for: " + wordForm);
                System.setProperty("wordnet.database.dir", "/home/dell/workspace/wordnet/WordNet-3.0/dict");
                WordNetDatabase database = WordNetDatabase.getFileInstance();
                Synset[] synsets = database.getSynsets(wordForm);
                //  Display the word forms and definitions for synsets retrieved
                if (synsets.length > 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("The following synsets contain '" +
                            wordForm + "' or a possible base form " +
                            "of that text:");
                    for (int i = 0; i < synsets.length; i++)
                    {
                        System.out.println("");
                        String[] wordForms = synsets[i].getWordForms();
                        for (int j = 0; j < wordForms.length; j++)
                        {
                            System.out.print((j > 0 ? ", " : "") +
                                    wordForms[j]);
                        }
                        System.out.println(": " + synsets[i].getDefinition());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.err.println("No synsets exist that contain " +
                            "the word form '" + wordForm + "'");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.err.println("You must specify " +
                        "a word form for which to retrieve synsets.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: with this you can also find multiple meaning of word, while with porter stemmer you'd get base form of words you were looking for. but if you wanna find higher meaning out of it this code will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying using a Porter stemmer algorithm instead of wordnet, you can find implementations in most languages - [including java here](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/java.txt)

This should get you what you want

Comment: Thanx.Actually i solved the problem by reading the documentation of jwnl.Using Morphological processor i can get base form of a word.for e.g sent=>send,children=>child..etc

Comment: List baseforms = dict.getMorphologicalProcessor().lookupAllBaseForms(POS.VERB, "sent");is a code example